# Scroll event listener not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mouseevent

I can't get an event listener to fire when scrolling. It works when clicking but not scrolling.

I want it to work even when the div it's listening for is created after the listener itself because of ajax usages. Therefore I use `.on` instead of `.scroll`.

```
$('.container').on('scroll', '.appended', function(){
    console.log('scrolling!');
});
```

I've created a JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/638Sx/4/).

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the listener to the append element. Like this :

```
var nAppend = $('<div class="appended">this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br>this is appended<br></div>').scroll(function(){
    console.log('scrolling!');
});

setTimeout(function(){$('.container').append(nAppend);},1000);
```

I updated your [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/638Sx/6/).

Answer (score 0):

Scroll events [don't bubble](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html), so the delegated approach won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mousewheel` event listener instead:

```
$('.container').on('mousewheel', '.appended' ,function(e){
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0) {
        console.log('scrolling up !');
    }
    else{
        console.log('scrolling down !');
    }
});
```